# Very basic Git for a complete a newbie

Tags: git

I'm a student trying to learn the basics of git. I've looked on-line for tutorials but they usually are a little too advanced for what I want to use git for.  All I want is a local git repository that tracks the previous versions of  my work.

So I understand the basics of git init, git add and git commit but how can I access older versions of a file? Git log shows a list of previous commits but how do I use this to retrieve older versions? For example I would like something like

```
git get commit c6af7ed0e10be25f4cc274989f1c556c1fefcc7f
```

also what command is required to tell git to record changes to a file? Must I run git commit every time I want git to record changes to the files being tracked?

Comment: What's wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide?rq=1 ?

Comment: if all you want is that, you might be better off with dropbox, google drive or similar, not with a full version control system like git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I access older versions of a file? Git log shows a list of previous commits but how do I use this to retrieve older versions?

Do

```
git checkout c6af7ed0e10be25f4cc274989f1c556c1fefcc7f
```

You can of course use other commit hashes to checkout other commits.

> Must I run git commit every time I want git to record changes to the files being tracked?

Short answer: yes